# Can't use my SimpleSVG Plugin in QGIS (error: initGui() method, 'QPYNullVariant')

Tags: qgis, error, svg

I'm looking for a good workflow from QGIS into a vector graphics program, and since the built-in SVG export in QGIS doesn't work really well, I thought I'd use the SimpleSVG plugin.

For some reason, I keep getting this error message when I open QGIS or try using the plugin:

`Couldn't load plugin simplesvg due to an error when calling its initGui() method
TypeError: QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPyNullVariant'`

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: 1]]

I've tried uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling it, and I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS (12.2.1-Lyon), the GDAL, numPY, and matPlotLib packages but...to no avail!

Comment: Could be a platform issue. The plugin works fine on Windows (or atleast Win7), perhaps someone can test this for Mac?

Comment: I have the same issue with qgis essen on a mac. Any progession on that topic would be nice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94698)